# Are recipes public domain?

Tags: copyright

I am writing a mobile app, and at the heart of it, I need to be able to leverage a large amount of food recipes. If I just scrape the internet and grab all of the recipes that I come across, is this legal? I've seen some different things with regards to whether or not a recipe can be copyrighted, but I'm still not totally clear on that. From what I've gathered, it seems like if a recipe is just a list of ingredients, then it cannot be copyrighted. However, if a recipe contains some sort of proprietary or new technique, then that particular technique could be copyrighted.

I just want to ensure that the method I use to get the recipes is totally legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publications International vs Meredith](https://cyber.harvard.edu/people/tfisher/IP/1996Publications.pdf) should provide you with the desired clarity. 17 USC 102(b) says

> In no case does copyright protection for an original work of
>   authorship extend to any idea, procedure, process, system, method of
>   operation, concept, principle, or discovery, regardless of the form in
>   which it is described, explained, illustrated, or embodied in such
>   work

The court found that

> The identification of ingredients necessary for the preparation of each dish is a
>   statement of facts. There is no expressive element in each listing;
>   in other words, the author who wrote down  the  ingredients for
>   "Curried Turkey and Peanut Salad" was not giving literary expression
>   to his individual creative labors. Instead, he was writing down an
>   idea, namely, the ingredients necessary to the  preparation of a
>   particular dish. "No author may copyright facts or ideas. The
>   copyright is limited to  those aspects of the work
>   -- termed 'expression'
>   -- that display the stamp of the author's originality."

and finally

> Although  the inventions of "Swiss 'n' Cheddar Cheeseballs" and
>   "Mediterranean Meatball Salad" were at  some time original, there can
>   be no monopoly in the copyright sense in the ideas for producing
>   certain foodstuffs. Nor can there be copyright in the method one might
>   use in preparing and  combining the necessary ingredients. Protection
>   for ideas or processes is the purview of patent.

Of course, that precludes copying the author's elegant description of live on the Riviera, which is protected literary work.